# How to solve this geeksforgeeks question for the given testcase?

Tags: c++

Please do not give geek for geek solution it won't work

Given k sorted arrays of size n each, merge them and print the sorted output.

```
int arr[][n] = {{2, 3, 5, 18},
                    {2, 8, 9, 17},
                    {1, 4, 7, 7, 8},
                    {1, 2, 3, 4},
                    {15, 17, 19}};
```

I tried this code there are too many 0's in output

```
// C++ program to merge k sorted arrays of size n each.
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define n 5


// A utility function to print array elements
void displayArray(int arr[], int size)
{
for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}

void mergeArrays(int arr[][n], int a, int output[])
{
    int c=0;

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n ;j++)
            output[c++]=arr[i][j];
    }
    sort(output,output + n*a);

}


int main()
{
    int arr[][n] = {{2, 3, 5, 18},
                    {2, 8, 9, 17},
                    {1, 4, 7, 7, 8},
                    {1, 2, 3, 4},
                    {15, 17, 19}};
    int k = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int output[n*k];

    mergeArrays(arr, 5, output);

    cout << "Merged array is " << endl;
    displayArray(output, n*k);

    return 0;
}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/amp/#aoh=15880638012294&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: I tried the same code with this test case it's not working. then I change the value of n to 5 and in main function from 3 to 5 but now it's showing many 0's in output. Check I have edited the question

Comment: Note that your arrays have a different size, in contradiction with the problem to be solved

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly. When you initialize an array with brace-enclosed list, every element that you don't set is initialized to zero, e.g.

```
int a[5] = {1, 2}
```

it's equivalent to

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 0, 0, 0}
```

The same is true for nested arrays, e.g.

```
int arr[5][5] = {{2, 3, 5, 18},
                {2, 8, 9, 17},
                {1, 4, 7, 7, 8},
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {15, 17, 19}};
```

is equivalent to

```
int arr[5][5] = {{2, 3, 5, 18, 0},
                {2, 8, 9, 17, 0},
                {1, 4, 7, 7, 8},
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 0},
                {15, 17, 19, 0, 0}};
```

Your array contains 5 zeros.

You can remove the zeros from the output with

```
void displayArray(int arr[], int size)
{
for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    if (arr[i]) cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Yes I do know that was my challenge to solve that there shouldn't be 0 using test case that's what my teacher asked me to do

Comment: @HrithikAgrawal If you know it, your whole question makes no sense. You sorted an array and you know that it contains 5 zeros. But you said  _there are too many 0's in output_. I added a version without zeros.